# Why do we multiply by combinations to respect order?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have just started studying a simple basic probability course since I am very weak at this subject. I am trying to solve a simple problem but I am confused about what my professor gave as an answer. Here is the problem:

> An urn containing 8 white balls, 8 black balls and 8 yellow balls. We draw 6 balls haphazardly. To obtain 2 balls from each color, is-it wiser to draw simultaneously, or one after the other without repetition, or one after the other with repetition?

When calculating the probabilty of this event $E$: "Having 2 balls from each color while the balls are drawn one after the other without replacement", I wrote as following: $$\mathbb{P}(E)=\frac{(A^2_8)^3}{A^6_{24}}$$
However, the professor said no there is an order and wrote: $$\mathbb{P}(E)=\frac{(A^2_8)^3\times C^2_6\times C^2_4}{A^6_{24}}$$
And I didn't understand why. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What does "with/without repetition" mean?  Do you mean "with/without replacement"?  And what does $A_m^n$ denote?

Comment: yes replacement and the $A^n_m$ means permutation with order and no replacement

Comment: Well, there are $\binom 82$ ways of choosing $2$ balls of a fixed color, hence $\binom 82^3$ ways of choosing $2$ balls of each color.  And there are $\binom {24}6$ ways of choosing $6$ balls with no restriction.  So it would seem that you just want the ratio $\binom 82^3\big / \binom {24}6$, no?  But perhaps I don't understand what you are computing.

Comment: I think the talk of ordered vs unordered has confused you.  Your computation is wrong....it would be correct if, say, you wanted the probability of drawing, say,  $WWBBRR$ in that order.  But you don't.  You'd be happy with any permutation of that.  That's what the "official" formula takes into account.  But I think it's much clearer to just stick with the unordered selections.

Comment: Lulu's answer and your professor's answer do give the same probability

Comment: Sorry guys I edited the question the event was uncorrect! I am compution the event "Having 2 balls from each color while the balls are drawn one after the other without replacement"